# Is there a cap on the number of Wasteland explorers?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Is there a cap on the number of Vault dwellers that can be sent to explore the Wasteland?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you may only have 25 explorers at any given time. At the same time, you may also have up to three teams of three dwellers performing quests, giving the grand total of dwellers that you can have outside your vault 34.